# How to get array back from rxjs from(array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs

Im trying to study rxjs and have one question.
I have for example `[1,2,3,4,5]` and do stream with `of([1,2,3,4,5])`
After that i use

```
of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .pipe(flatMap((array) => from(array))
```

to create iterable stream
and know only 1 way to get array back:

```
 .pipe(reduce(acc, data) => [...acc, data], []))
```

(or scan() but it needs takeLast(1) after, so i prefer reduce here)

so any another way to get array from iterable?

```
of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .pipe(flatMap((array) => from(array)))
  .pipe(reduce(acc, data) => [...acc, data], []))
```

Comment: `of` is designed to emit multiple items looks like your use case could do with `from`

Comment: How about the operator `toArray()`?  Docs [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/toArray)

Comment: toArray() works best! Vielen Dank! @dmcgrandle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toArray()` is the operator you are looking for.  Also, you can split an array into individual emissions with the `concatAll()` operator.

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { concatAll, tap, toArray } = rxjs.operators;

of([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  concatAll(),
  tap(item => console.log('item is ', item)),
  toArray()
).subscribe(
  result => console.log('result is ', result)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```